# Images fetched with axios not found in react/django

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django, axios

Am having problems using axios to fetch data containing images and strings from django backend. It just shows this error in my browser console:

> gig2_sWgfG4m.png:1          GET http://localhost:5173/media/gig2_sWgfG4m.png 404 (Not Found)

I have tried different configurations but still didn't get a positive response.
Here is my code:

CARD.JSX

```js
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/BlogHost'

export const Card = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(baseURL)
      .then((response) => {
        setPosts(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('An error occured while fetching data from backend', error)
      })
  }, [])


  if (!posts) return null;
  
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-400">
      <div className="mx-auto min-w-fit px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl py-16 sm:py-24 lg:max-w-none lg:py-32">

          <div className="mt-6 space-y-12 gap-y-6 gap-x-3 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid md:grid-cols-2 md:space-y-0 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-4 lg:space-y-0">
            {posts.map((post) => (
              <div key={post.title} className="group relative">
                  <div className="relative h-80 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white sm:aspect-h-1 sm:aspect-w-2 lg:aspect-h-1 lg:aspect-w-1 group-hover:opacity-75 sm:h-64">
                    <img
                      src={post.image}
                      alt={post.title}
                      className="h-full w-full object-cover object-center"
                    />
                  </div>
                <h3 className="mt-6 text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg text-gray-800">
                  <a href='{post.href}'>
                    <span className="absolute inset-0" />
                    {post.category}
                  </a>
                </h3>
                <p className="text-base md:text-xl lg:text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900">{post.body}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

BACKEND
VIEWS.PY

```js
from .models import Blog
from .serializer import BlogSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import render

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def BlogHost(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        blog = Blog.objects.all()
        serialize = BlogSerializer(blog, many=True)
        return Response(serialize.data)
```

Comment: Do you have a `settings.py` file, are you sure that it has the following configuration `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`?

Comment: It has that configuration